# Why would any widget ever be stateless?

Tags: flutter

What type of widget would not have a state/property that cant mutate? I cant think of anything possible.  Buttons have text, images have size, text has colors, etc etc.  What widget would ever not have some sort of property?

In the Flutter demo code "MyApp" is stateless, but it has properties. Why is this stateless and not stateful?

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Property != state.

Answer (score 2):

As per [documentation](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/StatelessWidget-class.html):

> Stateless widget are useful when the part of the user interface you
>   are describing does not depend on anything other than the
>   configuration information in the object itself and the BuildContext in
>   which the widget is inflated.

So what does this really mean? A `StatelessWidget` doesn't contain properties that it needs to track over time for changes - a text box for example, does.
A typical example of a `StatelessWidget` is a layout. It does contains children that might or might not respectively require maintaining state but your layout in and of itself doesn't.

A huge advantage of this is that `StatelessWidget` doesn't trigger a rebuild. Not ALL of your widget tree responds to a text box's text changing, only the parts that are tracked if and when they do change. Needless to say this has huge performance implications.

Answer (score 1):

There is two kind of state:

- external state: variables passed to the constructor, *InheritedWidget*, globals, etc...
- internal state: objects created by this widget.

A *StatelessWidget* is a widget with no internal state – but it can use external state.

A *StatelessWidget* will properly update when its parameters change (including when *InheritedWidget* updates).